# PyTest en Windows: "No se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutables"

Tags: python, windows

He instalado pytest mediante:

```
pip install --user pytest
```

Sin embargo, cuando he ido a ejecutarlo en un terminal me indica lo siguiente:

> No se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutables

¿Alguien sabe lo que puede estar ocurriendo? Gracias!!!

Comment: Intente: `python -m pytest [...]`

Comment: ¿Has añadido el PATH de python al sistema?

Comment: Si, porque la ejecución de python funciona perfectamente, es solamente con los py.test

Comment: Como dice David, hay que añadir el PATH, pero no solo de python, si no también del directorio \Scripts. Algo así como `C:\Python27\Scripts` ya que por defecto ahí es donde se alojan los paquetes añadidos a través de pip. (En el supuesto de que estés utilizando python 2)

Answer (score 0):

Añadí el PATH al sistema. Después esto funcionó para mi:

**python -m pytest test_hello.py**

```
    C:\Python37>pytest test_hello.py
    "pytest" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
    programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
    
    C:\Python37>python -m pytest test_hello.py
    ================================================= test session starts =================================================
    platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4rc1, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
    rootdir: C:\Python37
    collected 1 item
    
    test_hello.py .                                                                                                  [100%]
    ================================================== 1 passed in 0.02s ==================================================
```

Este es el test que probé (test_hello.py):

```
def test_hello_world():
    hello = "Hello World"
    assert hello.upper() == "HELLO WORLD"
```